# R: Adjusting Paths Between Computers - Easy Solutions?

Tags: r

I've created a few functions in R that are used across different computers and users.  The functions require input files, and therefore the paths within the functions must be updated when running on different computers.  This causes issues because many users have little coding experience (I am a novice myself).

My current solution is to save all of the important paths as variables at the very start of the code, and the variables are then referenced later in the code.  This works reasonably well: the paths can be updated in about 20 minutes even by a beginner.  However, some users don't understand how to update paths and know how to interpret the path-error message.  It's almost as if I need a prompt when running the function for the first time: "Did you update the paths to your input files on code lines 5, 6, and 7?"

The input files are large and usually hosted on external drives, so starting with generic paths like "~/Desktop/Folder/" isn't possible.

What strategies would you recommend for adjusting paths in an R code when switching between computers?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: There's a lot of exiting advice about there about this. See https://rstats.wtf/practice-safe-paths or https://ucd-cws.github.io/CABW2020_R_training/03_project_management.html for example. You can test if paths exists and throw errors if you want with `file.exists` and `stopifnot()`